# gfortran change/find out write buffer size

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran95

I have this molecular dynamics program that writes atom position and velocities to a file at every n steps of simulation. The actual writing is taking like 90% of the running time! (checked by eiminating the writes) So I desperately need to optimize that.

I see that some fortrans have an extension to change the write buffer size (called i/o block size) and the "number of blocks" at the OPEN statement, but it appears that gfortran doesn't. Also I read somewhere that gfortran uses 8192 bytes write buffer.

I even tried to do an FSTAT (right after opening, is that right?) to see what is the block size and number of blocks it is using but it returns -1 on both. (compiling for windows 64 bit)

Isn't there a way to enlarge the write buffer for a file in gfortran? Will it be diferent compiling for linux than for windows?

I'd really really rather stay in fortran but as a desperate measure isn't there a way to do so by adding some c routine?

thanks!

Comment: Are you doing formatted or unformatted output?

Comment: Buffered IO is controlled by the environment variable GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL=n.  I remember reading somewhere that the speed is not to do with the buffer sizes but the fact that it fflushes.  The C variant does not fflush after writing and runs  lot faster.

Comment: Thanks!
IanH I'm not sure what it is, sorry, noob here. It doesn't use format as of yet. If you mean what M.S.B. asketd, it's human readable.
cup, I'll check that on the manual, thanks! specially if gcc for windos (TDM64) uses that variable. No equivalent command line option?
"the c variant" you mean if it was written in c, right?

Answer (score 1):

IanH question is key.  Unformatted IO is MUCH faster than formatted.  The conversion from base 2 to base 10 is very CPU intensive.  If you don't need the values to be human readable, then use unformatted IO.   If you want to be able to read the values in another language, then use `access='stream'`.

Another approach would be to add your own buffering.  Replace the write statement with a call to a subroutine. Have that subroutine store values and write only when it has received M values. You'll also have to have a "flush" call to the subroutine to cause it to write the last values, if they are fewer them M.

If gcc C is faster at IO, you could mix Fortran and C with Fortran's ISO_C_Binding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding.   There are examples of the use of the ISO C Binding in the gfortran manual under "Mixed Language Programming".

Comment: It's human readable but doesn't use "format" when writing. But it's an option. I had considered my own buffer but didn't want to resort to that jsut yet. thanks! I'll read the c binding thing!

Comment: If its human-readable than you are incurring the high overhead of converting base 2 to base 10.  For unformatted IO use `form='unformatted'` in the open statement and simply `write (LUN) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you spend 90% of your runtime writing coords/vels every n timesteps, the obvious quick fix would be to instead write data every, say, n/100 timestep. But I'm sure you already thought of that yourself.

But yes, gfortran has a fixed 8k buffer, whose size cannot be changed except by modifying the libgfortran source and rebuilding it. The reason for the buffering is to amortize the syscall overhead; (simplistic) tests on Linux showed that 8k is sufficient and more than that goes far into diminishing returns territory. That being said, if you have some substantiated claims that bigger buffers are useful on some I/O patterns and/or OS, there's no reason why the buffer can't be made larger in a future release.

As for you performance issues, as already mentioned, unformatted is a lot faster than formatted I/O. Additionally, gfortran has rather high per-IO-statement overhead. You can amortize that by writing arrays (or, array sections) rather than individual elements (this matters mostly for unformatted, for formatted IO there is so much to do that this doesn't help that much).

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that if cost of IO is comparable or even larger than the effort of simulation, then it probably isn't such a good idea to store all these data to disk the first place. It is better to do whatever processing you intend to do directly during the simulation, instead of saving lots of intermediate data them later read them in again to do the processing.

Moreover, MD is an inherently highly parallelizable problem, and with IO you will severely cripple the efficiency of parallelization!  I would avoid IO whenever possible.

For individual trajectories, normally you just need to store the initial condition of each trajectory, along with its key statistics, or important snapshots at a small number of time values.  When you need one specific trajectory plotted you can regenerate the exact same trajectory or section of trajectory from the initial condition or the closest snapshot, and with similar cost as reading it from the disk.